# How can I translate this SQL Order By statement to LINQ-To-Object?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

This is the SQL ORDER BY :

```
order by case when [order] is null then 1 else 0 end, [order]
```

how to write it in LINQ-To-Object statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method Syntax**

```
var query = enumerable.OrderBy(x => x.order == null ? 1 : 0).ThenBy(x => x.order);
```

**Query Syntax**

```
var query = from x in enumerable
            orderby (x.order == null ? 1 : 0), x.order
            select x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming order is a nullable value (not an object), you should be able to use this:

```
orderby null == order ? 1 : 0, order
```

If it is an object, you could try

```
orderby null == order ? 1 : 0, order.PropertyName
```